# Google Calendar API - Requesting multiple scopes puts checkbox in authorization request?

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a Google Calendar API setup with Oauth2.

I can request only the calendar scope, but I want to add the `userinfo.email` scope.  When I add it using the `setScopes()` function like below the authorization request page does not automatically check the checkbox for the `CALENDAR_EVENTS` scope:

Only asking for `CALENDAR_EVENTS` scope:

```
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS]);
```

I get an authorization request like this:

[image]

When I request both scopes:

```
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']);
```

[image]

The user must check the calendar scope explicitly.  Most users will not read and check that scope.  So, I don't get the most important scope.

How to I get the `CALENDAR_EVENTS` scope to automatically check when requesting multiple scopes? The API is setup to allow that scope.

Answer (score 1):

These checkboxes are due to the rolling out of a new granular account permission system by Google. The behavior gets activated when the app is requesting access from different services. You can read more about this change in the blog [here](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/project-strobe/#:%7E:text=share%20with%20apps.-,Action%202,-%3A%20We%20are%20launching) and the Developer blog [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html).

It seems that the checkboxes are completely normal, and can not be turned off.

**Reference:**

- [More granular Google Account permissions with Google OAuth and APIs.](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html)
- [Google API Services User Data Policy.](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy)
- [Project Strobe: Protecting your data, improving our third-party APIs.](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/project-strobe/#:%7E:text=share%20with%20apps.-,Action%202,-%3A%20We%20are%20launching)