# How to translate json data to python object - Flask

Tags: python, json, oauth, flask, google-oauth

I'm trying to do a web application using the OAuthlib to login with google, this is what the google object looks like:

```
google = oauth.remote_app('google',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    request_token_params={'scope': 'email'},
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    consumer_key="my consumer",
    consumer_secret="my secret",
    base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/'
)
```

The problem I hve is when I get the user information from google, his is my authorization view:

```
@app.route('/login/authorized/<provider>')
def authorized():
    resp = google.authorized_response()
    auth_error(resp)
    id_token = json.load(resp['id_token'])
    login_user(me, True)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

So, what I try to do with the json.load is to decode the information google gives me, in this particular case, the response has an id_token which is a long string that, according to my research, is a json encoded string that when it is decoded, provides all the user information, no matter how much I try I can't seem to find the correct way to decode it, the error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

On the json.load line.

EDIT: after decoding the id_token I would then use it to get or create the user in my own database.

I am using Flask and the library is json.

If anyone could explain the correct way to decode the string into a python object I would appreciate it a lot, or if this is not json but some other type of coded string please do tell. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.load` [reads from a file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load). To decode a JSON **string**, use `json.loads`.

However, according to [these docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow), `id_token` is not JSON, but a ["JSON Web Token"](https://jwt.io/).

If you are looking for the "payload", you might try:

```
payload = json.loads( resp['id_token'].split('.')[1].decode('base64') )
```

Comment: if I use json.loads I get ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded, maybe I'm not explaining very well what google is returning, I would post it here but it is a very, very long string,

Comment: @JenaroCalviño If the token looks like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding, try decoding it first, as per my answer.

Comment: @JenaroCalviño Can you please provide your research that suggests the `id_token` is a JSON string?

Comment: this is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311836/how-to-identify-a-google-oauth2-user/13016081#13016081) taht suggests it is json, I printed the type of resp['id_token'] and it says it is unicode, and apparently decode('unicode') is not allowed

Comment: @JenaroCalviño Please see my revised answer. "JSON Web Tokens" are not simple JSON, but three base64-encoded JSON strings. See further, the documentation linked in my answer at [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Comment: thank you, that is correct, apparently if I paste my id_token in that webpage it decodes it, I'm reading now how I can decode it in my code

Comment: @JenaroCalviño I mis-spoke in my previous comment. The third string in a JWT, although base64-encoded, is not JSON, but a signature used to verify the previous two strings.

Answer (score 0):

As @this-vidor said my id_token was a JWT not JSON, and I was finally able to decode it using a library called jwt, I used jwt.decode(resp['id_token'], verify=False) and it worked! Just posting this in case anyone had the same problem and wanted a solution. Thank you very much.

For more information on [JWT](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pyjwt/latest/pyjwt.pdf)