# Can google user_id be changed?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-signin

We have an implementation of Google sign-in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth.

According to the documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo and the best practice (from the first link), google user_id (`sub`) is a unique identifier, and it can't be changed.

> `sub` > An identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never reused. A Google account can have multiple emails at different points in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your application as the unique-identifier key for the user.

However, we experience the scenario when we have an account in our system with the email from id_token, but google user_id is different with which it was registered previously.

Question: how it can be? Can I trust email from id_token and link new google_user_id to the internal account?

Comment: Any luck figuring out what caused this?  I've had a few users run into this issue also.

Comment: @Andrew, unfortunately not.

Comment: Are you limiting the length of `sub`? I'm running into the same issue and it causes users to be able to log in as someone else... any luck finding a solution here?

Comment: Google account emails can change, or be owned by multiple users, according to their documentation.
https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo